# PageSpeedInsights - effect of static assets caching on score and SEO

Tags: caching, seo, pagespeed, googlebot, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeedInsights shows "Leverage Caching of Static Assets" under Diagnostics section. On top of the section it mentions that this does not affect the score directly. 
As much as I understand, this means that caching may or may not improve the score. In what scenarios can it affect the scores indirectly? Also, pagespeed insights seems to load the page as first time user every time when calculating the scores, so it is difficult to correlate caching with the score.

For SEO, I understand the importance of caching for second time users, and I believe that googlebot also assigns some weightage to caching static resources, but there is no direct documentation available to corroborate that, It seems googlebot mostly depends on similar measures as PageSpeedInsights to figure out the speed signal for a web page, but is there some insight into how caching helps with that.

This is not a programming question, but as suggested on PageSpeedInsights documentation page,

> If you've got a question about using PageSpeed Insights that is
>   specific and answerable, ask your question in English on Stack
>   Overflow.

Happy to close it if it is too broad or off topic, but all i am really looking for here is some pointers to how caching affects scores and SEO, specifically with respect to PageSpeedInsights and Googlebot

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

**Real world speed** is considered by Googlebot so it is important there. Page Speed Insights (PSI) does not use it for it's scoring and the diagnostic is there just to make your site technically better and improve your visitor experience.

### Scores

It has no effect on the simulated scores (as you stated) in Lighthouse, the engine that PSI uses.

However if your site gets enough traffic for 'real world data' to show, these results **do include** return visitor speed monitoring at which point caching can make a big difference to your performance here.

This is the same data you would see on a paid Adwords campaign where it rates your sites page as 'slow', 'average' or 'fast' and the data Googlebot will use if it has enough of it (falling back to a variation of PSI if they don't have enough information. It is unknown what weights they use in their actual ranking algorithm and not worth trying to guess).

#### How to test the impact on scores

Run an audit through Google Chrome Developer Tools but uncheck 'Clear Storage' and compare it to your results with it checked. Most sites with properly implemented caching will receive a 10-15% increase in speed. This will give you a good idea of how it will impact your real world performance.

It uses Lighthouse to run it's tests, the same as PSI.

### SEO

I will mostly skip past this part as it isn't applicable to Stack Overflow and is opinion based but I would guess the weighting is really low / none existent in terms of 'technical checks' as there are legitimate reasons to use a short cache time on dynamically generated assets (e.g. A / B testing).

The only thing to add is Googlebot will see **real world speed** as part of it's speed calculations so the caching really helps there, hence the importance.

### Final Thoughts

Sadly there isn't much direct information on this and there doesn't seem to be any direct information on it's use on Googlebot.

I understand the curiosity but at the same time because it is soooo simple to implement I would be happy enough with an improved return visitor experience and not worry about the detail.